# How do I keep items in my Hibernate cache for at least 24 hours?

Tags: java, hibernate, memory, heap-memory, ehcache

We're using JBoss 7.1.3.Final, Java 7, and Hibernate 5.1.5.Final.  We start JBoss with these memory settings

```
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx25600m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
```

and this is our ehcache.xml config ...

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../config/ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false">

    <!-- This is a default configuration for 256Mb of cached data using the JVM's heap, but it must be adjusted
         according to specific requirement and heap sizes -->
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="750000"
         eternal="false"
         timeToIdleSeconds="86400"
         timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
         overflowToDisk="false"
         memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
    </defaultCache> 
    <cache name="main" maxElementsInMemory="750000" />

     <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
         class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
         properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=240.0.0.1,
         multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=32"/>

    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostName=localhost, port=40001,
        socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>    
</ehcache>
```

I would like items to stay in the cache for 24 hours.  However, what I have noticed is that when I use "top" to examine how much memory JBoss is using I see things like

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  8429 jboss     20   0 30.8g 2.1g  28m S 113.6  7.3 156:32.74 java
```

However, the "RES" number will drift during the day, going up to "10g" when traffic is heavy, and then falling down later in the evening when traffic is low.  Shouldn't the "RES" number stay high if items are living in the cache for at least 24 hours and we are not restarting JBoss?  Per my understanding, this number is correlated with the size of our heap, which contains the Hibernate cache.

Answer (score 0):

The `RES` column only shows the amount of physical memory *the entire Java process* is taking up at the moment. It has nothing to do with how much memory the hibernate cache is using.

Use `jstat` for Java heap stats. For accurate cache stats, use ehcache's own API.

Comment: We don't have jstat installed on our production machines (and it is not an option to do so).  And "entire Java process" includes the cache, no?  So maybe that number isn't completely accurate, but it would be influenced by the cache as it increases/decreases in size.

Comment: No, the RES number shows the amount of physical memory, i.e. the amount of memory that has not been swapped out by the OS. For instance your cache could be holding 4G worth of objects, but any part of that could be in either the physical memory or the disk. If you can't run jstat, you may have to build some heap/cache stat collecting code into your app by calling JVM and/or ehcache API.

Comment: The cache woudln't be on disk if there's enoguh memory to hanlde it though, right, because it hasn't been swapped out?  Couldn't I use "free -m" to validate that there is nothing being swapped?

Comment: What is "enough" is entirely at the OS' discretion :-). Just because you are running a 4G JVM process on a, say, 16G box doesn't mean none of it will be swapped out.

Comment: Thanks for answering all my questions.  One more -- if "free -m" reports "Swap:            0          0          0", then is it safe to assume no swap space is being used?  And by extension, can I then infer an upper bound on my cache based on "free -m"'s otehr output?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would mean that the server doesn't have any swap space configured.

Comment: And what about the part of my question, "and by extension ...", does that mean the other memory being used encompasses all of my cache?

Answer (score 0):

In Ehcache 2, I don't think you can see usage. However, Ehcache 3 can give it by looking at the tier statistics.

In your case, you might want to look at [sizeof](https://github.com/ehcache/sizeof). It's a library allowing you to know the size of things.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.  I'm not asking about number of items in teh cache, I'm asking about the memory its taking up.  If there's anything ambiguous about my quetsion, let me know so I can clear that up.